# Displaying PDF in a view in Android

Tags: android, android-file

In Android I need to display a PDF file, which is in the `asset` folder, in a view. Can anyone help me out with the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to display it in a view. You will have to make an `Intent` and then call an external program to do so.

```
File sd = new File("example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(sd));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(sd), "application/pdf");
try {
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    // Show a message that a PDF viewer is not installed
    Toast.makeText("No PDF reader available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```